# ASP.NET Core multiple dbcontext cannot add migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I have 2 DbContexts:

```
services.AddDbContext<ConfigDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:ConfigSQLServer:ConnectionString"].ToString(), t => t.MigrationsAssembly("App.Web")));

services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:AppSQLServer:ConnectionString"].ToString(), t => t.MigrationsAssembly("App.Web")));
```

when I try to run

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial -c AppDbContext
```

I get:

```
No DbContext named 'AppDbContext' was found
```

If I run:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext list
```

the result is:

```
FullNamespace.ConfigDbContext
```

It doesn't seam to find the second DbContext `AppDbContext`

ConfigDbCOntext:

```
public class ConfigDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ConfigDbContext()
    {

    }

    public ConfigDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

AppDbContext:

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
{
    public AppDbContext()
    {

    }

    public ConfigDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have similar setups, except that my DbContext and my IdentityDbCotenxt live in different assemblies other than the web project.

## ConfigDbContext

```
// Remove the parameter-less constructor

public class ConfigDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ConfigDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    rotected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

## AppDbContext

```
// Remove the parameter-less constructor
// Rename the constructor to AppDbContext, instead of ConfigDbContext

public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Also in my IdentityDbContext, if you change the primary key to `Guid`, I have to override `AppUserClaim`, `AppUserRole`, `AppUserLogin`, `AppRoleClaim` and `AppUserToken` as well.

## My example of IdentityDbContext

```
public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, Guid, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole,
    AppUserLogin, AppRoleClaim, AppUserToken>
{
    public AppIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<AppUser>().ToTable("User");
        builder.Entity<AppRole>().ToTable("Role");
        builder.Entity<AppUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");

        builder.Entity<AppUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        builder.Entity<AppRoleClaim>().ToTable("RoleClaim");

        builder.Entity<AppUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        builder.Entity<AppUserToken>().ToTable("UserToken");
    }
}
```

I don't think this is the issue but if my suggestions from the beginning don't fix the issue, might give this a trial.

Answer (score 0):

AppDbContext should be：

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```